# A generalization of Erdős-Ko-Rado theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, hypergraph

Is there any result known about the following generalization of the Erdős-Ko-Rado theorem?

Let $n, k, r, s$ be positive integers. We call a family $\mathcal{F}$ of $k$-element subsets of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$, an *$(r, s)$-intersection family* if among every $r$ elements of $\mathcal{F}$ at least two have an $s$-element intersection. What is the maximum size of such a family?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The case $s=1$ is Erdős hypergraph mathcing conjecture from

Paul Erdős (1965). A problem on independent $r$-tuples. Ann. Univ. Sci. Budapest. Eötvös Sect. Math. 8 (1965), 93–95.
[users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1965-01.pdf](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1965-01.pdf)

A recent paper about it is

Peter Frankl (2017) Proof of the Erdős matching conjecture in a new range, Israel Journal of Mathematics 222(1), pp 421-430 
[doi:10.1007/s11856-017-1595-7](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11856-017-1595-7)

The generalization you are asking about is studied in

Christos Pelekis, Israel Rocha (2017), A generalization of Erdős' matching conjecture. [arxiv:1710.04633](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.04633)

In the notation of this paper you are asking for the maximum number of edges in a $k$-uniform hypergraph, such that its $s$-matching number is strictly less than $r$. Their abstract says that they identify a collection of candidate solutions, and show that it contains the optimum when $n\geqslant 4k\binom{k}{s}r$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I truly appreciate your help.